# String to double number.(in format ##.###,##)

Tags: c#, .net, string, double

I need to know if there is a way to parse a `string` with a not ordinary format to `double`, for example:

```
string str = "1.500,43";
```

to

```
double num = 1500.43;
```

My attempt is not working. I am getting `0`:

```
double number=0;
double.TryParse("1.500,43", out number);
```

I know that I can just delete `"."`   and change `","` to `"."` and than do the `TryParse`, but I want to find another way.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: It is in  Italy bank.

Comment: If you're using TryParse you should test the result (boolean), unless the required behaviour is to default to 0 if the parse fails  - and that doesn't seem to be the case here as you're complaining about a result of 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use any [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IFormatProvider.aspx) with your [`double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) method, it uses your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) by default.

Probably your `CurrentcCulture`'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) or/and [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) properties doesn't match with `,` and `.`.

As a solution, you can [`.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone.aspx) your `CurrentCulture` and set these properties like;

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
double number;
if(double.TryParse("1.500,43", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                   culture, out number))
{
    // Successful parsing
}
```

In general, replacing your `.` and `,` with string methods is not a good idea.

Comment: You forgot to use the cloned `culture`.

Comment: @Mathew Ups, sorry. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Since we apparently don't want to default to 0 if the parse fails should we even be using TryParse here? Might it not be better to use Parse and let an exception be thrown if the parsing fails? Or, have an `if (!double.TryParse(... { do something` ?

Comment: @StephenKennedy Since we use `out` parameter modifier, `number` doesn't have to be initialize. Using `Parse` or `TryParse` is a matter of design to your program. If you wanna catch the exception when you can't parse your string, using `Parse` is of course the right thing. If you don't want _any_ exception when your parsing fail, `TryParse` is the right thing to do. Since OP used `TryParse` is his example, I used the same method. I deleted the default value of `number` and added if statement as well.

Comment: The point I'm making Soner is that if you use TryParse to suppress exceptions AND you are not happy to use zero as a default (as OP isn't) THEN you should check the result of TryParse and DO SOMETHING if it false. Your edit now addresses that so job done :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell `TryParse` which culture to use when trying to convert the string. The format you have is that used in Continental Europe with a decimal comma and a full stop for the thousands separator.

You could try the English format first and then the Continental one if that fails but there are cases that will convert to valid, but different, numbers if the thousands separator is omitted.

It would be better to insist that numbers are entered in one format or you pick the format from the user's locale. Though the latter approach can fail if you have someone using the site from different locale (an English person in Germany for example).

Comment: Uprated as indeed it is a good idea to insist on a certain input format.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `CultureInfo` is German you can use this:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("de");
double number = 0;
double.TryParse("1.500,43", NumberStyles.Number, culture, out number);
```

Of course this also works for other cultures where decimal separator and thousands separator are different. Just use the culture code of your country

Answer (score 1):

You can call .ToString and .Parse with the following parameter

new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()

On which you can set the NumberDecimalSeparator property to comma.

This way you don't need to mess with cultureinfo, but can set it on-demand basis.

Edit: Like so

```
double.Parse("1.500,43", new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()
                                                  {
                                                      NumberDecimalSeparator = ",",
                                                      NumberGroupSeparator = "."
                                                  });
```